Enemy script stops enemy from chasing after player
I have a script for a enemy where it can chase after the player and if close enough, close in and attack the player. If I jump over the enemy and if I time it right, the enemy will "closeIn" and "Attack" but then it will stop pursuing the player and idle instead.
Because I debugged it, I know that it stops pursuing because, while CanMove = false, it goes back to the "MoveMinorEnemy" method (because RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > MinimumDistanceToCloseIn) and then the code gets stuck in "MoveMinorEnemy" with the CanMove = false.
I cannot explain why it doesn't go back to CanMove = true. Here's the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkeletonWarrior : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 0.5f;
    private float MinimumDistanceToInitiateMove = 6f;
    private float MinimumDistanceToCloseIn = 3f;
    private float MinimumReachDistanceToInitiateAttack = 1f;
    private float RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer;
    private float AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer;
    private bool PlayerIsDetected = false;

    private Rigidbody2D SkeletonWarriorBody;

    private SpriteRenderer SkeletonWarriorRenderer;

    private Transform PlayerTransform;

    private Animator SkeletonWarriorAnim;
    private string WALK_ANIMATION = "Walk";
    private string ATTACK_ANIMATION = "Attack1";
    private string CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION = "CloseInToAttack";

    private bool IsGrounded = true;
    //private bool IsAttacking = false;
    private string GROUND_TAG = "Ground";

    private bool CanMove = true;



    // Start is called before the first frame update


    private void Awake()
    {
        SkeletonWarriorBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        SkeletonWarriorAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        SkeletonWarriorRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        //Player
        PlayerTransform = GameObject.Find("Knight").GetComponent<Transform>();
               
    }

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame    
    private void Update()
    {
        RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer = transform.position.x - PlayerTransform.position.x;
        AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer = Mathf.Abs(RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer);
        
        if (PlayerIsDetected == true)
        {
            ActIfPlayerIsDetected();
        }
        else if (AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer <= MinimumDistanceToInitiateMove)
        {
            PlayerIsDetected = true;
            ActIfPlayerIsDetected();
        }
        else
        {

        }

        //Debug.Log(AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer);
        //Debug.Log(CanMove);


    }

    private void ActIfPlayerIsDetected()
    {
                       
        if (AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > MinimumDistanceToCloseIn)
        {
            //if (CanMove == false)
            //{

            //}
            //else
            //{
                MoveMinorEnemy();
            //}
            
        }
        else if ((AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer <= MinimumDistanceToCloseIn) && (AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > MinimumReachDistanceToInitiateAttack))
        {
            CanMove = false;
            SkeletonWarriorCloseIn();
        }
        else
        {
            CanMove = false;
            SkeletonWarriorAttack();
        }
    }



    private void MoveMinorEnemy()
    {
        if (CanMove == true)
        {
            if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > 0)
            {
                SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);
                SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = true;
                SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);
            }
            else if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer < 0)
            {
                SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);
                SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = false;
                SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
            //
            //Debug.Log("This");
            //Debug.Log(CanMove);
            //Debug.Log(RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer);
            //Debug.Log(SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetBool(WALK_ANIMATION));
            //Debug.Log(SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION));
            //Debug.Log(SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetBool(ATTACK_ANIMATION));
            //SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);
        }
        
    }

    void SkeletonWarriorCloseIn()
    {
        //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
        //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(ATTACK_ANIMATION, false);
        if (/*SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(ATTACK_ANIMATION) ||*/ SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION))
        {

        }
        else
        {

            if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > 0)
                {
                    SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, true);
                    SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = true;
                    SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(-6 * speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);                                                                        
                }
                else if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer < 0)
                {
                    SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, true);
                    SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = false;
                    SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(6 * speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);                                                                          
                }
                else
                {
                
                }

        }
    }

    void SkeletonWarriorAttack()
    {
        //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
        //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, false);
        
        if (SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(ATTACK_ANIMATION) /*|| SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION)*/)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            

            SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(ATTACK_ANIMATION, true);

        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(GROUND_TAG))
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
            //CharacterAnim.SetBool(JUMP_ANIMATION, false);
            //Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);
        }

    }

    void AttackEnded()
    {
        SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(ATTACK_ANIMATION, false);
        
        CanMove = true;
        
    }
    void CloseInEnded()
    {
        SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);
        SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, false);
        SkeletonWarriorAttack();
    }
    
}

I've tried debugging almost everywhere, I feel it has to do with the
if (SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(ATTACK_ANIMATION) /*|| SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION)*/)
{
    
}

portion and that is why it doesn't start the animation and ultimately doesn't call the attackEnded anim event where CanMove is turned back to true.
Can someone help me understand how it gets stuck and how to solve my problem? I've been trying to find a solution for a long while now and I don't know how to proceed.

You shouldn't tag 'methods'  but 'unity' !

"Enemy script stops enemy from chasing after player" - that's because the enemy is actually a nice, friendly  guy :-)

I found the issue. I was declaring CanMove = false before entering the closeIn or Attack Method:
private void ActIfPlayerIsDetected()
{              
    if (AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > MinimumDistanceToCloseIn)
    {
        //if (CanMove == false)
        //{

        //}
        //else
        //{
            MoveMinorEnemy();
        //}
    }
    else if ((AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer <= MinimumDistanceToCloseIn) && (AbsolutePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > MinimumReachDistanceToInitiateAttack))
    {
        CanMove = false;
        SkeletonWarriorCloseIn();
    }
    else
    {
        CanMove = false;
        SkeletonWarriorAttack();
    }
}

Then the code entered the method and since the animation was already going on, it entered the first part of the if:
void SkeletonWarriorCloseIn()
{
    //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
    //SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(ATTACK_ANIMATION, false);
    if (/*SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(ATTACK_ANIMATION) ||*/ SkeletonWarriorAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer > 0)
        {
            SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, true);
            SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = true;
            SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(-6 * speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);                                                                        
        }
        else if (RelativePositionOfEnemyFromPlayer < 0)
        {
            SkeletonWarriorAnim.SetBool(CLOSE_IN_ANIMATION, true);
            SkeletonWarriorRenderer.flipX = false;
            SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity = new Vector2(6 * speed, SkeletonWarriorBody.velocity.y);                                                                          
        }
    }
}

By doing so, it never started another animation after CanMove was declared as false and therefore could not enter the AttackEnded event that turned back CanMove to true.
Just wanted to post the info in case it could help someone.
